# Should I delete an HTML element that is not appended to anything and I will no longer use?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I've built this temporary `input` element just so I can `tempInput.select()` it and then I can use `document.execCommand('copy');`

The function is like this (see snippet below):

```
function copyToClipboard() {
  const tempInput = document.createElement('input');
  const container = document.getElementById('myContainer');
  container.appendChild(tempInput);
  tempInput.value = 'SOME HIDDEN VALUE';
  tempInput.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  container.removeChild(tempInput);
}
```

```js
function App() {
  
  function copyToClipboard() {
    const tempInput = document.createElement('input');
    const container = document.getElementById('myContainer');
    container.appendChild(tempInput);
    tempInput.value = 'SOME HIDDEN VALUE';
    tempInput.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    container.removeChild(tempInput);
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div id="myContainer">App</div>
      <button onClick={copyToClipboard}>Copy</button>
      <input placeholder="Paste here..."/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

**QUESTION**

Even though the code is working as intended, I want to know if I need to delete (how would I do it?) the element `tempInput`? Or is calling `container.removeChild(tempInput);` enough?

Basically I want to know if what I'm doing is ok or should I take some extra step that I'm not aware of? The garbage collector would take care of this "floating" (not appended to anything) element?

Comment: `removeChild` is good enough

Comment: removeChild will remove the element from dom, so its ok